# How does the MAE and MSE criterion affect the way a tree splits in scikit's RandomForestRegressor()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I want to understand what actually happens when a node splits depending on the chosen 'criterion' in the latest scikit version of RandomForestRegressor (RFR).

RandomForestClassifier() has criterion options such as GINI Impurity and entropy to measure the quality of a split. In the GINI case, I know that feature boundaries that provide the max decrease in GINI impurity from one level to the next are chosen.

In RandomForestRegressor() the criterion options are 'MSE' and 'MAE'. But what is this error that is being measured and optimised before splitting?

Comment: Hi @Emmanuel! Which versions of `sklearn` are you talking about? As far as I know, sklearn have used `mse` / `mae` criterion for regression task and `gini` / other suitable criteria for classification tasks since `0.16` at least. And I guess, they had been used even earlier because of math behind it.

Regressor v0.16: https://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor
Classifier: https://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier

Comment: @MikhailStepanov Ahhh I see my error, I have gotten the two functions mixed up. However, I still don't understand how the 'mae' and 'mse' criterion work in the case of regression. So any explanation is still welcome please.

Comment: Since you now have cleared part of the confusion, please edit & update your post accordingly to remove stuff irrelevant to *regression*, which your question is actually about

Comment: You find a detailed answer why there are such criteria for classification and regression tasks, for example, in "Elements of statistical learning". It looks like this book is available free online. See page 309 for criteria for classification and p. 350 for regression task. Detailed answer is quite long and better suited for another site like the datascience.stackexchange.com